# logs are still showing "Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42" after upgrading tomcat to 7.0.054

Tags: linux, tomcat, catalina.out

i just upgraded tomcat to 7.0.54 from 7.0.42 and started it.. Everything is looking as expected but while starting the tomcat it showing "Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42" this line in logs..
i checked all my configurations again and but couldn't found from where that line is coming.
Please help me with this

Comment: its not hunged.. its working fine.. i just wanted "Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42" to be as "Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have upgraded correctly. If you unpacked new tomcat to new location, but left the CATALINA_HOME variable unchanged most likely you still start up the old tomcat and hence the logs.
So check if you don't have system variables set to point to wrong paths. If you overwrote the old instalation check if you really did it, in linux there would be typically read only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advise. I found the issue. I was overriding new tomcat on old tomcat. But i didn't replace new lib with old lib. After doing so, issue resolved

Comment: Please read [How to say thanks for an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you want to thank the person giving the answer, vote up and / or accept his answer.